# Alternativa para sustituir el SideMenu de JFoenix

Tags: java, javafx

Estoy trabajando con `JavaFX`, específicamente con la biblioteca [JFoenix](http://www.jfoenix.com).

En mi proyecto sustituí el `NavigationDrawer` del demo (`SideMenu`) por un `JFXListView` dentro de la interfaz (el espacio dentro del rectángulo rojo). La programación de los controladores es idéntica al demo, sin embargo cuando doy click en la opción "Etiquetas" no sustituye la tabla por el nuevo contenido.

¿Alguna idea de como solucionar esto?

*Captura de pantalla:*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para lograr lo que quieres prueba así:

1. Crea el `JFXListView` en el fchero xml, por ejemplo:

   ```
   <JFXListView
   fx:id="list"
   maxWidth="208.0"
   minWidth="210.0"
   prefWidth="208.0"
   style="-fx-margin: 0 0 0 10;"
   onMouseClicked="#submit"
   fx:controller="MainController">
       <Label fx:id="label1">Label 1</Label>
       <Label fx:id="label2">Label 2</Label>
   </JFXListView>
   ```

En mi caso lo puse en un fichero fxml llamado `Lista.fxml` que luego incluí dentro de `Main.fxml`. Fue necesario crear la asociación con el controlador `MainController`.

2. En el metodo `init()` del controlador `MainController` registra las clases a las que estarán enlazadas los Labels de la lista (siguiendo el ejemplo del demo):

   ```
   innerFlow.withGlobalLink(label1.getId(), ClaseControladora1.class);
   innerFlow.withGlobalLink(label2.getId(), ClaseControladora2.class);
   ```
3. Crea el metodo `submit` dentro del controlador para manejar el `onclick` sobre la lista:

   ```
   @FXML
   private void submit() {
   try {
   FlowHandler contentFlowHandler = (FlowHandler) 
   context.getRegisteredObject("ContentFlowHandler");

   contentFlowHandler.handle(list.getSelectionModel(). 
   getSelectedItem().getId());
   } catch (FlowException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (VetoException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
   }
   }
   ```

**Nota:** Tuve que agregar un espacio después de `getSelectionModel().` porque sino no se me indexaba el código aquí, ten cuidado a la hora de copiarlo, elimínale dicho espacio.

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Muchas gracias, resuelve mi problema